# Disabling an extension manually in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Im trying to disable the extension StayFocused, because it is blocking me after a reinstall of my system and it didn't save my settings for some reason.

Im trying to remove this extention altogether now but I can't remove it because it blocks me when I go to `chrome://extensions`. I will wait until tomorrow and try removing it, but there should be a way to remove extensions in any case, be it manually?!

*Windows 10 64-Bit, Chrome Version 53*

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to delete the folder of the StayFocused extension. They seem to be saved on Win10 at: `C:\Users\%%USERNAME%%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`

Inside each folder seems to be a folder with the extension version. Currently this was 1.5.7 for StayFocused, so I looked through each folder and found the one with this version number. Delete then restart the computer and remove the extension from Chrome inside the now working extensions tab.

Answer (score 0):

it's

`chrome://extensions`

and you are typing

`chrome://extentions` ,which is wrong.

Alternatively, press Ctrl+H and on the left hand side, select extensions.